# SQL Query to find total number of orders placed by customer

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble in writing a SQL query for php query, (for the Premiere Product Database). I have to get the total number of orders placed by a customer for a given customer number.

```
SELECT customername, firstname, lastname, COUNT(DISTINCT(customernum))
 FROM customer, orders, rep
 WHERE customer.customernum=orders.customernum  
 ANDcustomer.repnum=rep.repnum AND customer.customernum=customernum;
```

The code above gives me an error message **"#1052 - Column 'customernum' in field list is ambiguous"**.

Comment: Use a fully qualified column name for any field that is present in multiple tables.

Answer (score 2):

This means two or more of the tables concerned in your query have a field called `customernum` and it doesn't know which you're referring to. Prefix it with the table name.

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(your_table_name.customernum))
```

Comment: I get the same error message when I put `COUNT(orders.customernum)` with or without DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I removed the DISTINCT and `customer.customernum=customernum;` parts. Thank you